# jQuery ajax over https

Tags: jquery, ajax, .htaccess, http, https

I am having a problem with jQuery's ajax method over https.

The whole site is served over https. Most forms are submitted to a processing page via ajax. The url for the ajax function is basically:

```
$.ajax({
    "/assets/php/ajax/processor.php",
    ...
});
```

I also have a .htaccess file which redirects all http requests to https ones like so:

```
# Redirect any http requests to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The ajax works fine if I remove the redirect in the .htaccess file, but will not seem to work with it there. I assume this is because ajax functions over http (jQuery description of .ajax(): Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request) and therefore the .htaccess redirect is catching the ajax request.

I need the redirect because I don't want users of the site to use the http version (there is a sign in header on every page) but i need the ajax to work too and be secured by https.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: An ajax request using a relative url like the one you're using should go as an https request if the browser is currently pointing to an https domain. Can you provide any errors that are showing in the console when it "doesn't work"?

Comment: That's what I thought, but the RewriteCond seems to be catching the ajax request, which implies the request is not over https (RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rule to skip switching to https for the AJAX URI:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/php/ajax/processor\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: If I exclude the processor page from the https redirect, will the data being sent to the processor page still be encrypted?

Comment: No data going to `/assets/php/ajax/processor\.php` won't be encrypted. Sorry didn't know that you wanted to keep `/assets/php/ajax/processor\.php` always on https

Comment: Can you supply full URL in AJAX like `https://domain.com/assets/php/ajax/processor\.php`?

Comment: @anubhava You could use the full url, but you'll still run into CORS if you don't have it enabled on your server end. If you want to use the relative URL *with* your existing .htaccess file, you need to set the ACAO header.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the problem seems to have fixed itself. I think the browser had an older version of the ajax function cached which wasn't working correctly with https.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to your server's headers:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://yoursite.com`

Then your original .htaccess file should work as expected.